# Not able to ignore Rule in Eslint

Tags: eslint

I have the following in my .eslintrc (project here https://github.com/jrgleason/jest/tree/UPGRADE)

```
overrides: [
...
    {
        files: [
            'e2e/__tests__/**/*',
        ],
        rules: {
            'import/no-unresolved': "off",
        },
    },
]
```

But when I run I see...

> Code/jest/e2e/**tests**/haste_map_sha1.test.js
>     14:26  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'jest-haste-map'  import/no-unresolved

Why isn't it turning it off?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using an invalid json format:

```
    {
        files: [
            'e2e/__tests__/**/*',
            'packages/babel-jest/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/babel-plugin-jest-hoist/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/babel-preset-jest/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/eslint-config-fb-strict/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/eslint-plugin-jest/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/jest-changed-files/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/jest-circus/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/jest-diff/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/jest-docblock/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/jest-editor-support/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/jest/**/*.test.js',
            'packages/pretty-format/**/*.test.js',
        ],
        rules: {
            'import/no-unresolved': "off",
            'flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation': [2, 'always'],
        },
    },
```

These should be doublequotes.

**Update:** eslint supports JSON5, so try: 
`'import/no-unresolved': "off",`

Comment: That code isn't JSON, it's a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I can't do this because of a bug in ESLINT

See here https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9025